Why is multi-threading faster than multi-processing?
I am writing demonstration programs to illustrate various forms of concurrency.  They compute the mean over a large set of (pseudo-randomly-generated) integers.  I created two versions that use concurrent processes (one using mapped memory and the other a pipe for IPC) and a third that uses pthreads.  I used four workers (processes or threads) in each case, where the parent is counted as a worker.  I used a MacBook Pro with the Intel i7 Quad Core multi-processor (and OS Monterey). The input was a binary file of a billion (230) 4-byte integers. To compare performances, I timed only the code that changes between serial and parallel versions -- get_mean_serial and get_mean_parallel in the program below -- and used the pairs of times to compute speedup for the relevant subprogram in each version.
Both multi-processing versions show a roughly 2.33-fold speedup of parallel over serial, whereas the pthread version shows a 3.9-fold speedup, much closer to the theoretical upper bound. I am trying to account for the difference -- in particular, why the multi-processing result falls so far short of the ideal, where the pthread version serves as a "control" for comparison. I have considered the following possible explanations:

Per-process overhead. To check this, I changed the workhorse function get_mean_over_chunk to return a constant immediately, making the result computation  trivial, and leaving the set-up and management code -- mapping memory for the return values (means over subsets), fork, wait, and combining the partial results into the final answer.  These all turn out to take up hardly more thana millisecond, whereas the shortfall in the speedup with respect to the theoretical upper bound is about half a second.
Cache effects.  Each process reads its portion of the input only once, so the data have little locality, and, since the L3 cache is shared across all cores, the cache miss rate will be relatively high, and block replacement is effectively serialized across the four processes sharing the L3 cache. This explanation seemed plausible until I got the near-optimal result from pthreads.  Wouldn't the pthreads version have the same cache locality issues?  Presumably, the OS runs the threads one per processor, or using hyperthreading in pairs, but, either way, the caches are shared.
A hidden extra overhead caused by copy-on-write in the processor versions -- but each process only reads from the input mapped pages, and my measurement of overhead time already included any time needed for copying the shared page used for IPC.

Below is my whole program using processes and a mapped page for IPC.  The pthreads version changes get_mean_over_chnk to take a pointer to a structure type instance, where  both clients package their argument values in such structure type instances -- the parallel version using an array of args structures and passing a distinct element to each pthread_create call.
Below is the program that shows a 2.33 speedup for parallel over seriall computation of the mean, excluding common setup and reporting, which remain serial.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_WORKERS 4

FILE * fopen_checked(const char * const file, const char * const mode) {
    FILE * fp = fopen(file, mode);
    if (!fp) {
        perror("Failure to open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}

void * mmap_checked(size_t size) {
    void * mem = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Demand-zero memory allocation failure");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return mem;
}

long get_file_size(FILE * fp) {
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    return size;
}

double get_mean_over_chunk(const int * const nums, long start, long chunk) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    const int * end = nums + start + chunk;
    for (const int * ptr = nums + start; ptr < end; ++ptr) {
        sum += *ptr;
    }
    return sum / chunk;
}

double get_mean_serial(const int * const nums, const long num) {
    return get_mean_over_chunk(nums, 0, num);
}

double get_mean_parallel(const int * const nums, const long num,
        int num_workers) {
    long chunk = num / num_workers;
    double * means = mmap_checked(num_workers * sizeof(double));
    int num_children = num_workers - 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_children; ++i) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (!pid) {
            means[i] = get_mean_over_chunk(nums, i * chunk, chunk);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }
    means[i] = get_mean_over_chunk(nums, i * chunk, chunk);
    while (wait(NULL) > 0);
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < num_workers; ++i) {
        sum += means[i];
    }
    munmap(means, num_workers * sizeof(double));
    return sum / num_workers;
}

void print_elapsed_time(struct timeval * start, struct timeval * end) {
    time_t seconds = end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec;
    suseconds_t microseconds = end->tv_usec - start->tv_usec;
    if (microseconds < 0) {
        --seconds;
        microseconds += 1000000;
    }
    printf("Elapsed time: %ld seconds, %ld microseconds\n",
            (long)seconds, (long)microseconds);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <input-file>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE * fp = fopen_checked(argv[1], "r");
    long size = get_file_size(fp);
    int * nums = mmap_checked(size);
    long num = size / sizeof(int);
    fread(nums, sizeof(int), num, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    double mean_serial = get_mean_serial(nums, num);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Mean (serial): %f\n", mean_serial);
    print_elapsed_time(&start, &end);
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    double mean_parallel = get_mean_parallel(nums, num, NUM_WORKERS);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    printf("Mean (parallel): %f\n", mean_parallel);
    print_elapsed_time(&start, &end);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


Have you tried profiling it to see where it is spending most of its (wasted) time? My prejudice is that threads are lighter and more agile so less time is spent on admin. Worth increasing the number of threads/processes to see where the break even point is for N. Once you saturate memory or IO bandwidth (whichever happens first)  you generate more heat without any performance gain. It is worth finding that boundary if you have very compute bound functions.

Thanks.  I did not want to increase the number of processes because my hardware has four cores, so it would not be surprising to see a degradation beyond 4. Profiling is a good idea -- I will try that and report back.

As anecdata when I had a 4 core machine with hyperthreading 2x per core the optimum thread count for chess engines was around 6. Beyond that more heat and slightly slower.

I'm afraid profiling -- at least using gprof -- is not helpful, because it works at the level of function calls.  It's not surprising that most of the time goes into get_mean_serial, get_mean_parallel, and get_mean_over_chunk.  No functions get called some surprising number of times.

If it will compile under the Intel ICX compiler I'd recommend giving it a whirl on that. Their VTune tool is very good for finding hotspots and bottlenecks once you get used to it. Also its code generation is the best of the bunch for the sort of work that I do. YMMV

Since you use mmap the problem likely comes from the OS (or even possibly the driver). For example, page faults, the IO scheduler, etc. With threads, resources are shared while with processes resources are managed separately by the OS. This typically impact the IO scheduler. I am not sure Apple explain how such thing works (meanwhile Windows does this a bit and Linux is open-source so it is rather easy to check the code).

By the way, can you pin threads and processes to cores so to be sure context switches are not an issue (you should also avoid to run anything on the target core) ?

What about cache locking?  In the multiprocess case, does the L3 controller lock the cache whenever a line needs to be replaced, preventing the L2 and L1 caches of other processors from even reading from the shared L3 cache?  And, since threads are all in the same process, does the L3 controler not lock in that case?  That difference could explain the performance difference.

@Jérôme Richard — thanks for the suggestion about the IO scheduler and page faults.  On the other suggestion, could you please clarify this? — "You should also avoid [running] anything on the target core."  I do not quite understand that point.  Merci bien!

@Jérôme Richard — page faults strike me as the most plausible explanation so far.  I did try pinning the processes using sched_setaffinity on a Linux host and got parallel results slightly worse than serial — which strikes me as predictable.

@Jérôme Richard — Sorry! On second thought -- note that the input is copied into mmapped pages designated as MAP_SHARED -- so a page copied in on one process's page fault should be available for all child processes.  So that leaves hte puzzle open again.

I do not see any link between cache line locking and using threads versus processes.

"could you please clarify this?" I just meant that the core where you pin the thread/process should be reserved for your benchmark. If any other application are run on it then the number of cache miss can significantly increase while the goal was to check if the issue could be related to cache misses. Voilà ;) !

I can reproduce the problem on a Ubuntu 24.04LTS machine with an AMD Ryzen 7 5700U CPU (setup in performance mode) and 16 GiB of RAM, when comparing an OpenMP (spawning threads) implementation with one calling fork (spawning processes). Here are results for 10 runs on a 2 GiB file (compiled with -O3 -march=native -ffast-math -ffast-math):
With fork (processes):

Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 166574 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 138394 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 101580 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 102007 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 102029 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 100390 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 101907 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 102426 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 101231 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 102929 microseconds

With OpenMP (threads):

Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 137948 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 101365 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65413 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65030 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65675 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65088 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65720 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65878 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 64288 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 65364 microseconds

The results are not totally deterministic the threshold sometime appears after 2-3 iterations and sometimes more like 4-5. The overall behavior is fully reproducible and deterministic: the version spawning processes is always slower (both for the first iterations and the last ones). More specifically, the process-based version is always 55-60% slower for the last iterations (as we can see in the benchmark above).
If we profile the time of each process, here is what we get:
master time: 0.051009
worker time: 0.077518   <-----
worker time: 0.080153   <-----
worker time: 0.083232   <-----

We can clearly see that the master process is fast and the workers are slowed down by something. This is not the case with OpenMP threads:
worker time: 0.065331
worker time: 0.065738
worker time: 0.066835
worker time: 0.067679

A more-advanced profiling show that the thread-based version reach 1_000 page-faults/s while the process-based one reach 250_000 page-faults/s, that is 250 times more. . Additionally, the number of branch-misses/s is also much bigger for the process-based version: 6.5e6 vs 88.6e6. Meanwhile, the number of context switch is about the same for the two version (2000~2500 context-switch/s) as well as the number of instructions (10e9 instructions/s).
Assuming page-faults are the culprit, only the first touch of the target pages should be slow. Subsequent access should be fast. Thus, we can check if subsequent calls to get_mean_over_chunk are faster. Let's call it 10 times for sake of simplicity. Here are performance results:
With fork (processes):

Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 810084 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 665377 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 662304 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 659746 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 655561 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 660756 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 689288 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 659504 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 661921 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 662177 microseconds

With OpenMP (threads):

Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 921718 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 632878 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 635903 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 636173 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 631481 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 639544 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 636307 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 635677 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 634944 microseconds
Elapsed time: 0 seconds, 633128 microseconds

The results show that the process-based version execute subsequent calls the the function significantly faster. This confirms page-faults was the culprit. Note the number of page-faults/s is now 5 times smaller. The number of branch-misses/s is also now significantly smaller showing that this was a side effect of page faults (AFAIK some kernel code is running when page fault happens and this code tends not to be well predictable). The process-based version is still a little bit slower because the first iteration of the 10 are performing page faults. With 30 iterations, we barely see any difference.

— Thank you so much!  Extremely helpful!  I have follow-up questions, which I shall post one at a time.  First, the process version has 250 times more page faults than the OMP version.  Why?  Under this question — again — if the virtual pages are mapped as MAP_SHARED, but the page faults occur after fork, does the kernel still have to copy those pages for each process, rendering MAP_SHARED ineffective?  (That is my hypothesis.)   Even so, 250 is a huge factor.  Why?

— Second question — Sorry!  I do not totally follow your last remarks:  "The results show that the process-based version execute[s] subsequent calls [to] the the function significantly faster. " But I see the same pattern in both the process and thread versions — they do not look significantly different.  Could you please clarify?  Thanks!

My hypothesis is that the virtual pages are not mapped to a physical page because it would be too expensive to do that during the fork. Indeed, if all the pages of the forked process would be setup, then the time of a fork would be linear to the number of page, that is, generally the allocated space in physical memory. Delaying this operation not only improve the latency of the fork but also speed up the whole operation since not all pages are touched in practice (and this is generally true).

Because of this, accessing pages the first time results in an expensive page fault (the OS map the page to the same value than the parent). It is similar to mmap : pages are not actually physically map in practice. It is done lazily for sake of performance though you can explicitly request the OS to do so during a mmap. There is no physical copy. AFAIK, It is just mapping between virtual memory and physical one. Shared pages are truly shared: modifying one page make the result visible to other process sharing it (assuming a proper synchronization is done).

"Even so, 250 is a huge factor. Why?" Each worker process needs to do page fault on 4K/2M pages on a big chunk of memory. Meanwhile, the multithreaded version should perform no page fault during the computation since all pages are already touched.

"they do not look significantly different. " Sorry, I think the sentence is ambiguous. I meant that the subsequent call of the process-based version are faster than before, not faster than the multi-threaded one. In fact, they are very close to the multi-threaded version. The first call (which is not printed in the benchmark), is slower (same time as in the first benchmark where the function is called only once) and this is why all the timings of the process-based version are a bit slower. Another strategy could be not to consider the first call in the timings of both versions.
